# How to Cache json data from firebase to be available offline?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i hava json data that successfully display in recycler view and now i want to make it offline.my recycler view show the list and onclick list open a new subactivity to show the details and having a imageslider so i want to make it available both offline.my code is below

this is my mainactivity page:

```
public class

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_picnic);
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("picnic");
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerpicniclist2);
        search=findViewById(R.id.picnic_search2);

        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return true;
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        picniclist=new ArrayList<newpicnic>();
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    newpicnic n=dataSnapshot1.getValue(newpicnic.class);
                    picniclist.add(n);
                }
                adapter=new PicnicAdapter(picnic.this,picniclist);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(picnic.this,"Page is not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is class where i write set and get method:

```
    public newpicnic() {
    }

    public String getSpotName() {
        return SpotName;
    }

    public void setSpotName(String spotName) {
        SpotName = spotName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

    public List<String> getImg_url() {
        return img_url;
    }

    public void setImg_url(List<String> img_url) {
        this.img_url = img_url;
    }
}
```

this is my adapter:

```
    public PicnicAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<newpicnic>n){
        context=c;
        picnic=n;
        picnic2=new ArrayList<>();
        picnic2.addAll(picnic);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_picnic_list_item,parent,false);

        //new holder for picnic details
        final MyViewHolder viewHolder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        viewHolder.view_picnic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent p = new Intent(context,picnic_details.class);
                p.putExtra("spot_name",picnic.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getSpotName());
                p.putExtra("Description",picnic.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDescription());
                p.putExtra("Address",picnic.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getAddress());
                context.startActivity(p);
            }
        });
        return viewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.SpotName.setText(picnic.get(position).getSpotName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return picnic.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return  picnicDataFilter;
    }
    private Filter picnicDataFilter=new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            ArrayList<newpicnic> filteredList=new ArrayList<>();
            if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length()==0){
                filteredList.addAll(picnic2);
            }
            else {
                String filter=charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for(newpicnic dataItem:picnic2){
                    if(dataItem.getSpotName().toLowerCase().contains(filter)){
                        filteredList.add(dataItem);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
            results.values=filteredList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            picnic.clear();
            picnic.addAll((Collection<? extends newpicnic>) filterResults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView SpotName;
        LinearLayout view_picnic;
        TextView Description;
        TextView Address;

        public MyViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            SpotName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.SpotName);
            view_picnic=itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_root);
            Description=itemView.findViewById(R.id.picnic_description);
            Address=itemView.findViewById(R.id.picnic_address);

        }
    }
}
```

and this is my sub activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_picnic_details);

        Bundle r=getIntent().getExtras();
        pname=r.getString("spot_name");

        imgurl=new ArrayList<>();
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("picnic");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot list:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if (list.child("SpotName").getValue().toString().equals(pname)){
                        imgurl.addAll((List)list.child("img_url").getValue());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        //Recieve data
        String placname2=getIntent().getExtras().getString("spot_name");
        String placename=getIntent().getExtras().getString("spot_name");
        String description=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Description");
        String address=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Address");

        //in views
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout=findViewById(R.id.collapsingbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true);

        TextView picnicplacename=findViewById(R.id.place_name2);
        TextView picnicdescription=findViewById(R.id.picnic_description);
        TextView picnicaddress=findViewById(R.id.picnic_address);
        //setting vlaues
        picnicdescription.setText(description);
        picnicaddress.setText(address);
        picnicplacename.setText(placname2);
        //img_url
        carouselView=findViewById(R.id.picnic_carousel);

        loadcarousel();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadcarousel();
            }
        },5000);
    }
    public void loadcarousel(){
        carouselView.setPageCount(imgurl.size());
         //setting image carousel
         carouselView.setImageListener(new ImageListener() {
             @Override
             public void setImageForPosition(int position, final ImageView imageView) {
                 Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap().load(imgurl.get(position)).into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                         imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                     }
                 });
        }
    });
         //end of the slider
}
}
```

Comment: Use Database for offline storage

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use firebase database offline facilities with one single line:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

for more reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Hope this will help!!